# How to get the time of download

Tags: android, time, download

I need to get the time of download when I launch my android application. So, I added 2 Log and `System.currentTimeMillis()`. But, I can’t find the exact location to put these tools.

To get the start time, I added this :

```
period=System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("Début téléchargement : "+System.currentTimeMillis());
```

To ser the end time, I added this :

```
System.out.println("Fin téléchargement : "+System.currentTimeMillis());
period=(System.currentTimeMillis()-period);
System.out.println("La durée de téléchargement : "+period+"ms");
```

And this is all the code to download file :

```
class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
            int count;

            try {

                File vSDCard = null;
                if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
                    vSDCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                    File vFile = new File(vSDCard.getParent() + "/" + vSDCard.getName() + "/"
                            + "image.jpg");
                    URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
                    URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
                    int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
                    Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile);
                                        conexion.connect();

                    InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(vFile);
                    byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                    long total = 0;
                    while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                        total += count;
                        publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));
                        output.write(data, 0, count);
                    }

                    output.flush();
                    output.close();
                    input.close();

                    }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("ImageManager", "Error: " + e);
            }

            return null;
        }




        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
            Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", progress[0]);
            ProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
            dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
        }
    }
```

I need your suggestion please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First block before open URL connection or just before you start reding from input stream.

Second block after close of connection or just after the loop.

What's so difficult about it? Am I missing something ?

Comment: thank you a lot , I set the first and the second block just before and after 'conexion.connect();' and I compared the result with IDM. It gave the same result.

Comment: You can use nano time if you want more accuracy.